# Django and Oracle Database

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I'd like to connect an Oracle 8i database to Django. I tried using cx-Oracle, but the terminal output is 'cx-Oracle does not support this database'. If anyone know this please help.

I tried to connect with cx-Oracle.

Comment: Why 8i? That was released in 1998 and is over 20 years old. Can you not migrate the data to a newer version which is supported by `cx_Oracle`?

Comment: See also for why you really should upgrade to a supported version: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-404/Oracle-Oracle8i.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current versions of the cx_Oracle driver work with Oracle Client libraries 11.2 or later.  This means cx_Oracle can connect to Oracle Database 9.2  or later versions of the DB.

To connect back to Oracle 8i you would need to dig out a really old version of cx_Oracle, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-5-3  There's a chance you may need to use an old version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`cx_Oracle` github page](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/):

> #### About cx_Oracle
>
> `cx_Oracle` is a Python extension module that enables access to Oracle Database. It conforms to the Python database API 2.0 specification with a considerable number of additions and a couple of exclusions.
>
> `cx_Oracle` 8.3 has been tested with Python versions 3.6 through 3.10. Older versions of `cx_Oracle` may be used with previous Python releases. You can use `cx_Oracle` with Oracle 11.2, 12, 18, 19 and 21 client libraries. Oracle's standard client-server version interoperability allows connection to both older and newer databases. For example Oracle 19c client libraries can connect to Oracle Database 11.2.

and

> #### Features
>
> - Easily installed from PyPI.
> - Support for Python 3.6 and higher. Older versions of cx_Oracle may be used with previous Python releases.
> - Support for Oracle Client 11.2, 12, 18, 19 and 21. Oracle's standard cross-version interoperability, allows easy upgrades and connectivity to different Oracle Database versions.
> - Connect to Oracle Database 9.2, 10, 11, 12, 18, 19 or 21 (depending on the Oracle Client version used).

The earliest supported version listed for the latest `cx_Oracle` version is Oracle 9.2.

---

Looking back through the [release notes](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/5.3/releasenotes.html#version-5-3-march-2017) (linked from the earliest github tag):

> #### Version 5.0 (December 2008)
>
> - Added support for Python 3.0 with much help from Amaury Forgeot d’Arc.
> - Removed support for Python 2.3 and Oracle 8i.

If you want to use it with Oracle 8i then you will need to find a `cx_Oracle` version prior to 5.0! (and use it with Python 2 and Django 1.11 LTS.)